# EC2 - Docker container dir increase in size

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, containers

I am running a docker compose setup on a AWS EC2 instance with three docker container.
After a few weeks running my docker images the size of the /containers dir increases quite a bit:

```
8,1G    /var/lib/docker/containers
0   /var/lib/docker/plugins
3,1G    /var/lib/docker/overlay2
```

When I stop all my images and remove them and the containers and restart my docker images it looks like this:

```
96K /var/lib/docker/containers
0   /var/lib/docker/plugins
3,1G    /var/lib/docker/overlay2
```

A docker image prune --all did not free anything.
So how can I prevent the var/lib/docker/containers from growing that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens because you are writing data into the container itself. you should write data to an external volume. each time you write data into the container, a new layer is created on top of the current image.

after a while, your /var/lib/docker/container will be collecting a lot of layers of changed/written file and keep growing

each time you stop your container, the layers are removed, and you are back to the original state of the image when you build them.

Quote:

> Containers that write a lot of data consume more space than containers
> that do not. This is because most write operations consume new space
> in the container’s thin writable top layer.
>
> Note: for write-heavy applications, you should not store the data in the container. Instead, use Docker volumes, which are independent
> of the running container and are designed to be efficient for I/O. In
> addition, volumes can be shared among containers and do not increase
> the size of your container’s writable layer.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/